# Request Content-Length 265529745 exceeds the configured limit of 31457280

Tags: scala, snappydata

I am trying the streaming example of snappydata from url 
https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/snappy-poc

When I submit the job using command

> ./bin/snappy-job.sh submit --lead localhost:8090 --app-name
>   AdAnalytics --class
>   io.snappydata.adanalytics.SnappySQLLogAggregatorJob --app-jar
>   SNAPPY_POC_HOME/assembly/build/libs/snappy-poc-1.0.0-assembly.jar
>   --stream

I get error

> Request Content-Length 265529745 exceeds the configured limit of
>   31457280

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that your app jar is too big to upload and submit to job-server. How big is your app jar and see if you have other unnecessary dependencies bundled along with it? You need to remove those dependencies.

Comment: It is around 250MB and I need all dependencies.